# What do the @EnableConfigurationProperties Javadocs mean regarding "standard Spring Beans"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[The Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.4/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/EnableConfigurationProperties.html#value--) for the `value` element of `@EnableConfigurationProperties` states:

> Convenient way to quickly register [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) annotated beans with Spring. Standard Spring Beans will also be scanned regardless of this value.

I am confused by this sentence: "Standard Spring Beans will also be scanned regardless of this value."  I'm not sure what a "standard Spring Bean" is in this context, and how it differs from a "`@ConfigurationProperties` annotated bean".  It sounds like there's a certain class of bean which will always be scanned for configuration properties, and certain class that won't.

To the best of my understanding, a non-`@ConfigurationProperties` won't be affected by the presence or absence of `@EnableConfigurationProperties` in the application config.  It's not completely clear to me from reading the [Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.4/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-enabling) either.

So in short, what *does* the `value` element of the annotation do?  Why is there the need to differentiate between "standard Spring Beans" and "`@ConfigurationProperties` annotated beans"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `@ConfigurationProperties` is not going to register a spring bean.

So if you had

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyCustomProperties { 
  ...
}
```

Spring would not create a bean for `MyCustomProperties.class`

But if you had

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = MyCustomProperties.class)
public class MyConfiguration{
  ...
}
```

then `MyCustomProperties` would be created as a spring bean

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html)

> public @interface ConfigurationProperties Annotation for externalized
> configuration. Add this to a class definition or a @Bean method in a
> @Configuration class if you want to bind and validate some external
> Properties (e.g. from a .properties file).

So the annotation `@ConfigurationProperties` is designed to be used with some other annotations that invoke the creation of a spring bean so that it validates the properties being read.

`@EnableConfigurationProperties` is just an extra case where it tells Spring that some classes that bring the `@ConfigurationProperties` should be used to create spring beans even if no other annotation is used on those classes like `@Configuration` or `@Component` (ex MyCustomProperties.class).

Comment: Got it. So `@EnableConfigurationProperties` turns on configuration properties scanning.  Adding the `value` element to it also generates beans for the given classes.

Comment: I think I see where I got confused.  "`@ConfigurationProperties` annotated beans" was me misparsing/focusing on the wrong part of the sentence.   Looking more carefully at the full context, "Convenient way to quickly register `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated beans" isn't saying that they're beans already, it's saying that it's registering them as beans.